# Presenting lock screen on top of main storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, storyboard

When a user is entering the app either from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`, I would like to display a lock screen.

I have the lock screen set up in another storyboard, not on the main one.

If I instantiate the lock screen storyboard and then move to the main storyboard, the app will not keep the same state of when the user left the app, when entering the app with  `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

So if the user is in a specific view controller and then leave the app and enter again with `applicationWillEnterForeground`, the storyboard will be instantiated as the lock screen storyboard and once the user will unlock the screen he will be redirected to the `rootViewController` of the main storyboard, and not to the view controller he was at before.

The main storyboard starts with a UITabBarController.

How do you overcome this?

```swift
if let lockedViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Locked", bundle: .main).instantiateInitialViewController() {

    window?.rootViewController = lockedViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Lock screen storyboard:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: use separate window for lock screen

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example or article you know on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create new instance of `UIWindow` and keep reference in your appdelegate.

On foreground transition create new window and on unlock release window

```
private var lockWindow:UIWindow?
func createNewWindow()  {
    lockWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    lockWindow!.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Locked", bundle: .main).instantiateInitialViewController()
    lockWindow!.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1;
    lockWindow!.isHidden = false
}

func releaseWindow() {
    self.lockWindow?.isHidden = true
    self.lockWindow = nil
}
```